# Circuit for capacitor charging and IC enable

Tags: capacitor, esp8266, inrush-current

I'm trying to find a solution to a problem I have where I need to drive an ESP8266 from a power source that is rated for 250 mA.

The ESP8266 will have an average current way lower than 250 mA but it can have an instantaneous current draw that is close to double that.

So I put a large capacitor to average out the current and take care of the spikes, but now the capacitor will lead to a large inrush current instead.

I would like to slowly precharge the buffer capacitor and when the voltage across it is around 3 V I'd like to enable the ESP8266.

I'm considering a simple comparator that enables the ESP and bypasses a series resistor with a MOSFET, but I'm not sure if that is a good idea. I feel like there has to be something like this that exists but I don't know what to search for.

Comment: 250mA seems to be low, I uses 500mA LDO for my ESP8266 design, in fact Adafruit made the same mistake by using a 250mA LDO in their initial ESP8266 board design that they eventually replaced with AP2112. Another thing is instead of adding large capacitor,  add(or replace) the output ceramic capacitor with a tantalum capacitor with low ESR value.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your power source please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *load switch* would do the trick for your inrush current protection.

See here for some options:
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/power-management-pmic/power-distribution-switches-load-drivers/726

These work similarly to how you described except the MOSFET doubles as the resistor until the inrush charging is complete and as a switch afterwards.
As an example, see the block diagram for the Diodes AP2265*
https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP22652_53_52A_53A.pdf

For your application, be sure to choose a part that, upon overcurrent, current limits and does not latch off (e.g. AP22652/53 for the example).
You probably also don't want output discharging.

To my surprise, it seems like the ESP8266 does not have built in "Brown Out" or "Undervoltage" detection.

The proper way to resolve this is with a *voltage supervisor*. See here for a selection:
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/power-management-pmic/supervisors/691

These are basically what you describe: a comparator on the power rail but only for enable/reset signals.